# Find posterior distribution for the variance in a regression with normally-distributed X

Tags: self-study, bayesian, posterior

Consider a univariate regression

$$ y_t = \alpha + \beta x_t + \epsilon_t,$$

where $x_t \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma^2_x)$ and $ \epsilon_t \sim N(0,\sigma^2_\epsilon)$.

The prior distribution is of the form

$$ p(\mu_x, \sigma_x, \alpha, \beta, \sigma_\epsilon) \propto p(\alpha)/(\sigma_\epsilon \sigma_x),  $$

where $p(\alpha) \propto 1$.

I need to find the posterior distributions for all parameters. I was able to find the posteriors for $\alpha, \beta$ now, but got stuck for $\sigma_\epsilon$. Denote $\theta^{-j}$ as the set of parameters excluding parameter $j$. Here is my attempt:

1. I start with: $p(\sigma^2_\epsilon | \text{data}, \theta^{-\sigma^2_\epsilon}) \propto p(\text{data}|\theta) p(\sigma^2_\epsilon) $
2. I find $p(\text{data}|\theta) \propto (\sigma^2)^{-T/2} \text{exp}\left\{ -\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_{t=1}^{T} (y_t - \mu)^2 \right\}$, where $\mu = \alpha + \beta \mu_x$ and $\sigma^2 = \beta^2 \sigma_x^2 + \sigma^2_\epsilon$, and $T$ is the number of data points.
3. The prior $p(\sigma^2_\epsilon) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma^2_\epsilon}$.

I don't know how to separate $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ from $\sigma^2$, which make the manipulation for the posterior extremely difficult. I am suggested that the posterior here follows an inverse gamma distribution. I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: is $x_t$ part of the data ?

Comment: I think $x_t$ is part of the data.

Comment: then you expression for $p(data|\theta)$ should be different. Note that $p(x,y|\theta) = p(y|x,\alpha,\beta,\sigma^2_{\epsilon}) p(x|\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)$

Comment: I see. Now I got $p(\sigma^2_\epsilon|\alpha, \beta, y, x) = IG(\frac{t}{2}, \frac{\sum (y_t - \alpha - \beta x_t)^2}{2})$. Does this look correct?

Comment: Well it is in the form you expected. Note that this is the *conditional* probability, i.e. for a given value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If you want the *marginal* probability (depending only on the data), you will have to integrate over $\alpha$ and $\beta$.